# Android: Can't inflate class fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to understand how fragments work, but i haven't had sucess so far.
This is only an example nothing usefull.
 when i try to add a fragment to the layout I get always the same error. 
I don't know what is missing

Fragment Class

```
  package com.app.danieltavares.teste;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class TestFragment extends Fragment{

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.testefrag,container,false);

    }
}
```

ActivityClass

```
package com.app.danieltavares.teste;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Layout Fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="diusdb"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Layout that uses the fragments

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.app.danieltavares.teste.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.app.danieltavares.teste.TestFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/testefrag"></fragment>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Logcat

```
08-23 18:35:21.867 15308-15308/com.app.danieltavares.teste E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.app.danieltavares.teste, PID: 15308
                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.danieltavares.teste/com.app.danieltavares.teste.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                                                                          Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                          Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #16: Must specify unique android:id, android:tag, or have a parent with an id for com.app.danieltavares.teste.TestFragment
                                                                             at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2282)
                                                                             at android.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:98)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5884)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:34)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:80)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:777)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:136)
                                                                             at com.app.danieltavares.teste.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6664)
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #16: Must specify unique android:id, android:tag, or have a parent with an id for com.app.danieltavares.teste.TestFragment
```

Add an `android:id` attribute to the `<fragment>` element in your layout file.